# firefox extension: Link recognition (without href tag) in FireFox 4.0

Tags: firefox-addon, hyperlink

`Firefox 4.0` has a new feature that it can recognize URLs which has no `href` tag (simple text). So if you right click on such a selected text it would show link options (i.e. open link in new tab...).

How can I leverage this feature (where and what to code) and access the selected text (which is potentially a link)?

Is it possible to access the sting array of multiple selected texts (one potential link per line)?

Currently my `context menu` Firefox-addon is shown when a user right click a link, nut I need it to be shown when the user right click on a link or a potential link.

Answer (score 0):

You should text for non-null, non-empty gContextMenu.linkURL property (string) or non-null gContextMenu.linkURI.

```
if (!!gContextMenu.linkURL) {
  if (gContextMenu.onSaveableLink) {
    // regular link (supported protocol)
  else if (gContextMenu.onLink) {
    // regular link (external protocol)
  )
  else {
   // plain text link
  }
}
```

- [Code](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/nsContextMenu.js#128)
- [Unit tests](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/test/browser_plainTextLinks.js) (demonstration)